# Hover tooltiptext in Rascal figure

Tags: figure, rascal

Is it possible to produce a figure in Rascal that shows a tooltiptext during hover? I mean the little yellow thing like the one prescribed by the `title` attribute of a `<a>` tag in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

yes in these slides (http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jurgenv/teaching/evolution1314/slides/intro-visualization.pdf) an example is shown:

```
FProperty popup(str S){
 return mouseOver(box(text(S), fillColor("lightyellow"),
 grow(1.2),resizable(false)));
}

box(size(50),fillColor("red"), popup("Hello"))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I am trying it out right now, I will accept it as soon as I understand how to do it!

Comment: did this work? I just advised somebody else do to try it out :-)

Comment: Good question. I remember saying this 2 years ago, and I do not remember if this worked. Sorry. I'm not able to either, for the coming two weeks.

Comment: Let's see what the new guys report!