# Horizontal axis for bar chart

Tags: rascal

According to a pdf, which was shared in a previous [post about tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299595/hover-tooltiptext-in-rascal-figure), on page 70, it mentions the possibility to draw bar charts.  However, a picture mentions "work in progress" and indeed, Rascal does not seem to support this.

Is there already a possibility to draw a horizontal axis, representing a bar chart, where the text of the categories can be written?

Pdf: [Towards Visual Software Analytics](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~jurgenv/teaching/evolution1314/slides/intro-visualization.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hcat` and `vcat` to put labels under the respective boxes. For example you could draw a bar and its label wrapped in a `vcat` and then `hcat` all bars next to eachother, aligned at the bottom using something like `hcat([b1, b2, b3],std(bottom()))`.

references:

- http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Figure/Figures/vcat/vcat.html
- http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Figure/Figures/hcat/hcat.html